# css button effect doesn't work

Tags: html, css

but my website display this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqmSk.png)

I copied the css code to my website, it display like picture 2. What should I edit?

my website: http://www.giterwork.acsite.org/member/signup.php

Comment: Please, provide your problem code.

Comment: Thank you and I have replied :)

Answer (score 0):

it is my code :)

```css
#button {
    background-color:#3bb3e0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px 20px;
    padding-right:50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(44,160,202) 0%, rgb(62,184,229) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, rgb(44,160,202)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(62,184,229))
    );
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 10px 5px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 10px 5px #999;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 10px 5px #999;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 5px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 10px 5px #999;
}

#button:active {
    top:3px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(62,184,229) 0%, rgb(44,160,202) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, rgb(62,184,229)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(44,160,202))
    );
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 2px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 5px 3px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 2px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 5px 3px #999;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 2px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 5px 3px #999;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #2ab7ec, 0px 2px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 5px 3px #999;
}

#button::before {
    background-color:#2591b4;
    background-image:url(../images/right_arrow.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    content:"";
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:15px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #052756, 0px 1px 0px #60c9f0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #052756, 0px 1px 0px #60c9f0;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #052756, 0px 1px 0px #60c9f0;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #052756, 0px 1px 0px #60c9f0;
}

#button:active::before {
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-12px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #60c9f0, 0px 3px 0px #0e3871, 0px 6px 3px #1a80a6;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #60c9f0, 0px 3px 0px #0e3871, 0px 6px 3px #1a80a6;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #60c9f0, 0px 3px 0px #0e3871, 0px 6px 3px #1a80a6;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #60c9f0, 0px 3px 0px #0e3871, 0px 6px 3px #1a80a6;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />
  <title>美利集团线上加盟系统</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" id="form1" name="form1" method="POST">
      <table class="main_table">

        <tr>

          <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
    </form>
    <br />
  </div>
<div id="footer"></div></body>
</html>
```